# Restrict properties in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is there better solution for restricting property names then following?

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "not": {
        "anyOf": [{
           "required": ["a"]
        }, {
           "required": ["b"]
        }]
    }
}
```

I would like to accept any properties except `a` or `b`. Solution about works, but it's quite complicated and validation errors message in my python validator is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is nice and readable.  I can see how it produces odd validation errors (`not` always makes those complicated), but I would say the schema itself explains the constraints quite well.

You could do it a few bytes shorter using `oneOf` (e.g. `{"oneOf": [{}, {"required": ["a"]}]}`), but I don't think it's readable.

You could also do something horrible with `patternProperties` (i.e. make a regex that matched anything except `"a"`/`"b"` and then use `additionalProperties`), but again I think that's less readable.

I think the solution you have is good.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in how to do this with patternProperties, you could do this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "[aA]": {
            "not": {}
        },
        "[bB]": {
            "not": {}
        }
}
```

I needed a similar solution to support the rejection of case insensitive property names. As of draft 4, the implementations I used don't support the regex pattern "/i" to ignore case.